# Launching multiple tabs via Process.Start opens 1 fewer than it should

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5, process.start

I have an event that iterates over each selected row in a GridControl and and passes a Cell value to this method:

```
    public void SearchForException(string ex)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ex))
            return;

        var sb = new StringBuilder();

        if (ex.IndexOf("svn", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)
            sb.Append("SharpSVN ");

        sb.Append(ex);

        Process.Start(string.Format("https://www.google.com/search?q={0}",
            Uri.EscapeDataString(sb.ToString())));
    }
```

I tried 2 tests:

- Call event when I already have my default browser open
- Call event when I do not have my default browser open

Test #1 launches N new tabs in the current window.
Test #2 launches a new window with N-1 tabs.

When i step through my code, Test 1 and Test 2 both open up N tabs.

I tried adding `Thread.Sleep(25)` at the end of my `SearchForException` method, and that works... But I was wondering if there's a more proper way around this? If the user has a slower browser (read: Internet Explorer) as their default 25ms might not be long enough.

Comment: One possible approach, although it conflicts with the "use the user's choice of browser" goal, is described by Raymond Chen [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/10/21/10458557.aspx)

Comment: `a slower browser (read: Internet Explorer)` -- Sorry, Why do you think `Internet Explorer` is slow? I find `Fire Fox` is much slower, why didn't you mention it? the starting times of `Internet Explorer 9` and `Google Chrome` are almost the same.

Comment: @KingKing Well, testing out the code with various durations for Thread.Sleep, IE requires a much longer period to start up than Chrome in order to open the correct number of tabs. I could've just as well said FF because that is fairly slow as well, I just kind of forgot about it since I don't have a reason to use it anymore, whereas many intranet sites require IE.